# Convert VisualStudio project custom build steps to Qt/MSBuild

Tags: c++, msbuild, qt5, visual-studio-2019

I have found this [post](https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/01/24/qt-visual-studio-new-approach-based-msbuild) from Qt talking about **Qt/MSBuild** as a replacement of **custom build steps**. I am trying to convert my project to use Qt/MSBuild. I have created a blank c++ project and added some project files. All builds just fine with the old **custom build steps** options.

When I right-click on the solution and selects: **Convert custom build steps to Qt/MSBuild** it throws this error message: **Warning: No projects to convert**. But, I have 2 projects in the solution.

[image]

I susspect that there are some basic project configuration I have missed. Or maybe because I do not have a Qt project file (.pro). Do you have any ideas?

I had a look on the property pages for one of my ui files but could not find the Qt/MSBuild option either:
[image]

My software:

- Qt version: 5.13.0
- Visual studio version: 16.3.7
- Qt Visual Studio tools version: 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would never ever (never in a million years) use **custom build steps** in visual studio, nor would I ever in a million years use what-ever QT replaces them with. I find usually that custom build steps are super inflexible. BTW: I have installed this QT/MSBuild tool once and over 3 years have never touched it. Usually using a tool to generate code for you is a recipe for getting project files that are thousands of line long and filled with massive duplication. This is because the makers of the tools, some of the time, do not understand the MSBuild syntax.

Instead you could simply write a custom code that takes a fraction of the space, and you will have more control. Don't ever cede understanding about what is in your project files to some tool that may or may not do what you want.

I have seen c++ projects files that use QT and were generated by CMake that used 'custom build steps' and were 8000+ lines long. I was able to replace them with a project file that was 20 lines long. Which is more maintainable?

What I would suggest is to write custom build targets that run before or after your build.
These are documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2019

If you want to perform a certain action after a build, you could write a custom target, and use the special attribute called `AfterTargets`.

```
<Target Name="DoStuff" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Message Text="I'm a muffin" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="bla bla bla" DestinationFolder="bla bla bla" />
</Target>
```

Your choices for what to assign the `AfterTargets` attribute are almost limitless. You can choose `Build` for when the entire build is completed. You could choose `Compile`, or `Link` or a host of others.

Conversely, if you want it to run *before* some target, you could choose instead to use the attribute `BeforeTargets`.

```
<Target Name="PrepareSomething" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Message Text="Gettin ready for the build..." />
  <Copy SourceFiles="bla bla bla" DestinationFolder="bla bla bla" />
</Target>
```

In this case it would call your target before the build executes. You can look at the link I put up to find more options.

The place to put these code snippets is inside of one of your *.vcxproj files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your vcxproj file? At `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` attribute there is a node with `<Keyword></Keyword>`. If inner text is `Win32Proj` or something like it, juts change it to `QtVS_v302`. This would help you to use Qt/MsBuild.

Comment: Sorry, cant do any more. I don't have access now.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same today.  The problem is that you created a non-QT application.  The QT build tools are not invoked unless you use one of the Qt new-project types:
[image]

What is interesting is when you create a QT application in one directory, create a standard Windows application in another (with the same project name), and compare the project files.

You will find that in the QT application vcproj there is this additional item:

```
  <ImportGroup Condition="Exists('$(QtMsBuild)\qt.targets')">
    <Import Project="$(QtMsBuild)\qt.targets" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

The `$(QtMsBuild)` refers to the "Globals" section in the vcproj file.  Here it is declared as:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{B12702AD-ABFB-343A-A199-8E24837244A3}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>QtVS_v303</Keyword>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">10.0.18362.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">10.0.18362.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-w-Syms|x64'">10.0.18362.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <QtMsBuild Condition="'$(QtMsBuild)'=='' OR !Exists('$(QtMsBuild)\qt.targets')"
  >$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\QtMsBuild</QtMsBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

whereas in a vanilla Windows app it will be:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>15.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{B12702AD-ABFB-343A-A199-8E24837244A3}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

What is slightly concerning is that some settings such as the following are *not* defined in the QT version *(for the version of QT VS tools that I am using)*:

```
<UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
<WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
<CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
```

***There are a few more property sections in addition to what I've shown here.***

So it may be possible to hack the vcproj file to enable QT support, although I  would not personally recommend it.

---

[edit] So after doing all of that, the dialog still appears, and the MOCs are not generated before issuing a build.  Needed to add this to the vcxproj to coax the MOC generator to run:

```
<QtMoc>
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  <AdditionalUsingDirectories>%(AdditionalUsingDirectories)</AdditionalUsingDirectories>
  <OverrideClCompile>extend</OverrideClCompile>
</QtMoc>
```

---

and furthermore, you may need to right-click on some of your header files, select `properties` and change the "item type" to MOC (alternatively change `ClInclude` to `QtMoc` in the vcxproj file):
[image]

What a royal PITA it can be....